# What HTML text encoding exactly corresponds to MySQL charset "latin1"?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

What HTML text encoding exactly corresponds to MySQL charset "latin1"? ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-15, or another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually the same as cp1252, which is actually a Windows code page. In terms of the ISO standards, it's closest to ISO 8859-1, except that it defines a few more characters (such as the Euro symbol).

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around - Latin-1 is the informal name of ISO-8859-1, while Windows-1252 is mostly the same (but not quite).

Comment: That's true, but MySQL's "latin1" encoding is the same Windows-1252.

Comment: Oh, that's confusing :-) You are right, as this page says: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-we-sets.html

Answer (score 3):

[`ISO-8859-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is the official name of Latin-1.